# java.lang.VerifyError: f/i/b/f in Android 4 after upgrade gradle from 4.0.1 to 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Recently, we just upgraded gradle from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
...
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

But after the upgrade, we are encountering

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: f/i/b/f
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>(FragmentHostCallback.java:64)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>(FragmentHostCallback.java:58)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:871)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:82)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:87)
       at com.yocto.wenote.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:115)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
       at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.newActivity(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:9)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

in Android 4 devices.

Anyone has idea what is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered this problem just few days ago, only for obfuscated release builds.

To solve this, I just added the following rule to ProGuard configuration:

```
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled to find a workaround for the same issue. Alternatively to Daniel's solution, the problem also does not appear if I use 'proguard-android.txt' instead of 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'